# Performance of PostGIS Query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-query, optimization

Here's my query

```
SELECT "building"."id", 
"building"."details", 
"building"."status", 
ST_AsGeoJSON("building"."center")::json, 
ST_AsGeoJSON("building"."geometry")::json 
FROM "building" WHERE ST_Intersects(
    "building"."center",
    ST_MakeEnvelope(-157.91061401367188,21.197376124303936,-157.72951126098633,21.340868251190965,4326):: geography('POLYGON')
)
```

There are around 500,000 records in my database. These buildings' data are from OSM. I am trying to get the buildings that are inside a bounding box. It takes ~ 50sec to complete the query. My data will grow over time. It might take more time if data grows.

I have indexed my `center` column

```
CREATE INDEX "IDX_32ed92783d0144c88d8094b0ac" ON "building" USING GIST ( center );
```

My EXPLAIN and ANALYZE:

```
"Index Scan using ""IDX_32ed92783d0144c88d8094b0ac"" on building  (cost=0.28..35.80 rows=1 width=175) (actual time=6.473..146.382 rows=9792 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (center && '0103000020E61000000100000005000000000000C023BD63C08AE5DE3D87323540000000C023BD63C0231C4724435735400000002858B763C0231C4724435735400000002858B763C08AE5DE3D87323540000000C023BD63C08AE5DE3D87323540'::geography(Polygon,4326))"
"  Filter: st_intersects(center, '0103000020E61000000100000005000000000000C023BD63C08AE5DE3D87323540000000C023BD63C0231C4724435735400000002858B763C0231C4724435735400000002858B763C08AE5DE3D87323540000000C023BD63C08AE5DE3D87323540'::geography(Polygon,4326))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 105"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1313"
"Planning Time: 21.729 ms"
"Execution Time: 147.195 ms"
```

How can I improve my query performance and reduce response time?

Comment: Please use text to present the EXPLAIN plan. Images are not legible on all devices.

Comment: I updated it in a readable form.

Comment: Have you tried to store the `Envelope` geometry in other table in order to intersect 2 tables ? Take a look at the function `ST_DWithin` to optimize your intersect filter : https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

Comment: the query plan shows it is taking 147ms, so less than 1 second... the 49 other seconds are spent somewhere else (establishing the connection, receiving the data, displaying it or whatever)

Comment: @J.Monticolo Storing `Envelope` geometry in another table and intersecting 2 tables won't slow the query? Wouldn't that is extra work that query has to do?

Comment: the query plan shows it is reading from cache. Try the `explain (buffers, analyze)` with another envelope. If you have a slow disk, retreiving the data from disk the 1st time may be your botleneck

Comment: @JGH. I am selecting `center` and polygon `geometry` too. That is needed but that is costing me extra time.

Comment: Is your query returning about 500,000 rows, including generated GeoJSON? That's going to take a while, depending on your system and client. How fast is it if you do a "SELECT count(*) FROM ..."? Then you know where the problem is.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Total records `500,000`(which is likely to grow) and query returned record `~10,000`.Yes, it will return generated GeoJSON. My RDS size is `db.t3.micro`

Answer (score 1):

Using && would probably boost your performance. Take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191666/vs-st-intersects-performance

```
    SELECT * FROM "your_schema"."your_table" 
    WHERE "your_schema"."your_table".geometry &&
    ST_MakeEnvelope(min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat, your_epsg)
```

Comment: Considering they only compare points ("center") against the search envelope, I am not convinced that && is going to help.

Comment: @bugmenot123 It's skipping function invocation, at least...and it's unnecessary. So better use the right tool.

Comment: It's not going to make a huge difference but worth doing. I updated my query as suggested but no significant change.